# R3F: Canvas is not part of the THREE namespace! Did you forget to extend? error after restarting the program

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

My program was working until i restarted the project and now im getting the error , i was trying to make an overlay to when i clicked the marker , it worked and now there are bugs, here's my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import { Html, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Vector3, TextureLoader } from 'three';
import { FaMapMarkerAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';
import Overlay from '../Overlay'; // Adjust the import path as necessary
import colorMap from '../../assets/textures/8k_earth_daymap.jpg'; // Adjust the import path as necessary
import { useThree, useLoader } from '@react-three/fiber';
let imgProjects = [
  'https://placehold.co/100'
];

function Marker({ position, onClick }) {
  return (
    <group position={position}>
      <Html>
        <div style={{ color: 'orange', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={onClick}>
          <FaMapMarkerAlt />
        </div>
      </Html>
    </group>
  );
}

export function Earth() {
  const { camera, gl } = useThree();
  const overlayRef = useRef();
  const [selectedMarker, setSelectedMarker] = useState(null);
  const [selectedPosition, setSelectedPosition] = useState(null);
  
  const latLongToVector3 = (lat, lon, radius) => {
    const phi = (90 - lat) * (Math.PI / 180);
    const theta = (lon + 180) * (Math.PI / 180);
    return new Vector3(
      -radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta),
      radius * Math.cos(phi),
      radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta)
    );
  };

  const markers = [
    { lat: 40.7128, lon: -74.0060, name: 'New York', imageUrl: imgProjects[0] },
    // Add more markers as needed
  ];

  const handleMarkerClick = (marker) => {
    setSelectedMarker(marker);
    const position = latLongToVector3(marker.lat, marker.lon, 1.5); // Assuming your globe's radius is 1.5
    setSelectedPosition(position);
  };

  const [colorMapTexture] = useLoader(TextureLoader, [colorMap]);
  
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <directionalLight color="#ffffff" intensity={2} position={[1, -5, 5]} castShadow />
      <mesh receiveShadow>
        <sphereGeometry args={[1.5, 32, 32]} /> {/* Assuming your globe's radius is 1.5 */}
        <meshStandardMaterial map={colorMapTexture} />
        {markers.map((marker, index) => (
          <Marker
            key={index}
            position={latLongToVector3(marker.lat, marker.lon, 1.5)}
            onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(marker)}
          />
        ))}
      </mesh>
      {selectedMarker && (
        <Html>
          <div ref={overlayRef} style={{ position: 'absolute', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)' }}>
            <Overlay marker={selectedMarker} />
          </div>
        </Html>
      )}
      <OrbitControls enableZoom={true} enablePan={true} enableRotate={true} />
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

Tried using chat gpt and other ai but they all say my code is clean , and it was working , it all began when i tried to position the overlay on top of the marker using the ai as helper